# Odd sizing policy behavior

Tags: qt, layout

I'm trying to place a text label next to a spin box in a horizontal layout. I want the label to be as small as possible, and the spin box as large as possible, so I set the label's horizontal sizing policy to `Minimum` and the spin box's horizontal sizing policy to `Maximum`. However, This results in the label having the maximum size and the spin box having the minimum size:

[image: Backwards layout]

If I swap the sizing policies, I get what I want:

[image: Correct/desired layout]

Is this backwards behavior a known bug, or am I just not understanding something about Qt layouts?

Using QtCreator 2.7.0 based on Qt 5.0.2 (32-bit) on 64-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"minimum" means that the widget must have the given size or more (the given size is a minimum), while "maximum" means that the given size is an upper limit, so the behaviour you observe is consitent with semantics.

I would set the spinbox policy to "expanding" and the label to "preferred".

Comment: Yeah that worked - figured it was just a misunderstanding on my part